# Convert downloaded com.google.api.services.drive.model.File to Bitmap or Uri

Tags: android, bitmap, google-drive-api

I am downloading some images from google drive. And after that i want to show them in my android application but i am not able to figure out how to convert this file type to a bitmap or any alternate type so that i can show these images in my application.Here is the code to download the files. Please help me out if anyone knows the answer.

```
 com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = service.files().get("file path").execute();
//how to converet this file into bitmap or Uri
```

Comment: What version of Google Drive SDK are you using?

Comment: Looks like [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk). V3 is too new and GDAA it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't have to convert these file types to bitmap you have to download images from fetched google drive file from file.getDownloadUrl() and then convert it into bitmap.

```
File file = service.files().get(files[i]).execute();

HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
InputStream is = resp.getContent();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(is);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

Comment: The question was "how to convert com.google.api.services.drive.model.File type file to bitmap or byte data"  and i was unable to get image file from this type of file. I think you didn't understand the question.